# _this6.function is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I work on react-native and I have this error :

> _this6.callGeocodage is not a function

my code :

```
callGeocodage(adress) {
 console.log(adress);
  }

  renderAd(item, index) {
    return (
      <Card style={{ elevation: 3, width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}>
        <CardItem cardBody>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.callGeocodage(item.adress)}}>
            <IconFontAwesome name={ICON_SEARCH} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text>{item.adress} </Text>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
    );
  }
```

Someone know why ??

Comment: try to bind your `callGeocodage` function in the constructor like so `this.callGeocodage = this.callGeocodage.bind(this);`

Comment: Write Function as following  `callGeocodage = (adress) => {
    console.log(adress);
  };`

Comment: Please show us how `renderAd` is called

Comment: @MartinShishkov No, the problem is not that it's not bound but that it's not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind this to renderAd in constructor :

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.renderAd = this.renderAd.bind(this);
}
```

Or use it as an arrow func :

```
const renderAd = (item, index) => {
```

Comment: I try with renderAd = (item, index) => { and it's OK thank you